# How do we link testplans in azure devops with test script in the pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Hi guys needed some help,  i have a pipeline for running my automation tests and testplans where i have maintained test cases i just want to map my testplans with test scripts in the pipeline.

I have'nt been able to find anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.